# Scylladb : scylla_io_setup script iops calculation not matching with other iops calculation tool like fio

Tags: scylla

I have 3 nodes containerized scylla cluster. At the launch of scylla container , scylla calculate iops (read and write)  for mounted disk . I see iops rate calculated by scylla_io_setup is much lower compared to fio tool.

IOPS Number for scylla_io_setup

```
disks:
  - mountpoint: /var/lib/scylla
    read_iops: 264
    read_bandwidth: 84052448
    write_iops: 1197
    write_bandwidth: 129923792
```

IOPS using fio

```
    read_iops: 70000
    write_iops: 60000
```

Soo many(around 6k got it from grafana) write request to scylla are blocking on commitlog,i am seeing  write latency issue with scylla.

Comment: What kind of disk is this? Maybe it's shared with another workload that is interfering with the measurement?

Comment: Nop it is dedicated disk for scylla , and no other workload was going on when the scylla docker calculating the iops . disk type is xfs. user@ip:~$ df -T /data/cassandra/
Filesystem                      Type  1K-blocks      Used  Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/uptycssdd-cassandra xfs  1952015108 268380844 1683634264  14% /data/cassandra

Comment: What type of disk is this? A cloud network disk, and SSD, an HDD?

Comment: How were your running fio? What were its inputs/jobfile? What were its outputs?